# Run-time error 1004 when refreshing tables

Tags: excel, vba

I've been getting

> Run-Time Error '1004' Application-defined or object-defined

error every time I hit 'Refresh All'. When I hit Debug the following line of code is highlighted.

```
Set FoundOrder = wsSale.Range("A:A").Find(What:=orderNum)
```

The program executes without an error. The only time that I get an error is when I refresh the tables to get UpToDate information.

Here's my code. It's written for onChange event of a combo box on "Mailing" Sheet.

```
Private Sub CustName3_Change()

Dim wsOrderD As Worksheet: Set wsOrderD = Sheets("OrderDetails")
Dim wsSale As Worksheet: Set wsSale = Sheets("Sales")
Dim wsCust As Worksheet: Set wsCust = Sheets("CusTO")
Dim wsMail As Worksheet: Set wsMail = Sheets("Mailing")
Dim regEx As New RegExp
Dim orderNum As String: orderNum = CustName3.text

With regEx
    .Pattern = "^[0-9 ]+$"
End With

Dim FoundOrder As Range: Set FoundOrder = wsSale.Range("A:A").Find(What:=orderNum)

If FoundOrder Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox ("Order#" & orderNum & " Not Found")
    CustName3.text = ""
    Exit Sub
End If

wsMail.Range("AK10").Value = orderNum

If orderNum = "" Then
    wsMail.Range("v8:v15").Value = ""
    wsMail.Range("x3:af3").Value = "".
Else
    If regEx.test(orderNum) Then
        Dim custId As Long: custId = wsSale.Range("A:A").Find(What:=orderNum).Row
        custId = wsSale.Cells(custId, "C")

        Dim FoundCell As Long: FoundCell = wsCust.Range("A:A").Find(What:=custId).Row
        Dim RowToFind As String: RowToFind = FoundCell

        wsMail.Range("v8").Value = "¤Ø³ " & wsCust.Cells(RowToFind, "B")
        wsMail.Range("v9").Value = wsCust.Cells(RowToFind, "C")
        wsMail.Range("v10").Value = wsCust.Cells(RowToFind, "D")
        wsMail.Range("v11").Value = wsCust.Cells(RowToFind, "E")
        wsMail.Range("v12").Value = wsCust.Cells(RowToFind, "F")
        wsMail.Range("v13").Value = "ÃËÑÊä»ÃÉ³ÕÂì   " & wsCust.Cells(RowToFind, "G")
        wsMail.Range("v14").Value = "â·Ã  " & wsCust.Cells(RowToFind, "H")
        wsMail.Range("v15").Value = "â·Ã  " & wsCust.Cells(RowToFind, "I")
    Else
        MsgBox ("Please type in 'Numbers' only!")
        CustName3.text = ""
        wsMail.Range("AK10").Value = ""
        Exit Sub
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry, I've edited the post now.

Comment: Where is this code placed?

Comment: This code is for a combo box that I have on "Mailing" sheet for onChange event.

Comment: put a break point on that line. seems like the onchange is firing when you are refreshing. Is the combobox picking values from the table?

Comment: Yes, the combo box reads values from "CusTO" sheet.

Comment: What can I do if the onchange is firing when I refresh?

Comment: you can set `enableevents=false` but then i need to see the file before i can confirm that

Answer (score 0):

By far the most common cause of a run-time Error 1004 is when VBA code refers to a named range that doesn’t exist. Perhaps the name is spelled wrong in the code. Or maybe an invalid name is used.

```
CustName3.text
```

I think this is not defined

Comment: Thanks for helping Erjon! The CustName3.Text refers to a value chosen in a combo box that I have on "Mailing" sheet.

Comment: you have to post the entire code then, but run-time Error 1004 means that you have something undefined

Comment: That is not even on the line that has the error. Please do not guess at answers. Use a comment to clarify the issue instead.

Comment: His line has `orderNum`, and the debug shows that line cause in this line `orderNUm` is called :P

Comment: `CustName3` is not defined. Try replacing it with a dummy string for example "Foo". will you get the same error????

Comment: Try replacing `wsSale.Range("A:A").Find(What:=orderNum)` with something that is in `.Range("A:A")` and tell us if you get again the error

Answer (score 0):

I solved this finally by using `enableevents=false`. The program seems to get executed when refreshing. I also have to disable background refresh on all connections as well. Big Thanks to Siddharth Rout!